Routing radiused edges between nodes in TikZ
I am trying to route an edge between two nodes that starts vertically, then turns horizontally, and finally turns back down as it ends.
When I add a radius, the edge is incorrect.
How can I fix the first radius?
\documentclass[letterpaper]{report}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows}

\begin{document}

\tikzset{decision/.style={
    diamond,
    draw,
    rounded corners,
    text centered,
    text width=0.4in
}}

\tikzset{arrow/.style={thin,->,>=stealth,rounded corners}}

\tikzset{x=1in,y=1in}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node (condition0) [decision] at (0,0) {foo};
  \node (condition1) [decision] at (3,0) {bar};
  \draw [arrow] (condition0) |- ++(0,0.5) -| (condition1);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}



If you move the auxiliary coordinate to the right it should work. Now it moves up, only.

Simply use \draw [arrow] (condition0) -- ++(0,0.5) -| (condition1);.

You could use the ext.paths.ortho tikz library. Using it, you won't need an auxiliary coordinate and thus avoid the problem in the first place:
\documentclass[letterpaper]{report}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows}

\begin{document}

\tikzset{decision/.style={
    diamond,
    draw,
    rounded corners,
    text centered,
    text width=0.4in
}}



\tikzset{arrow/.style={thin,->,>=stealth,rounded corners}}

\tikzset{x=1in,y=1in}

\usetikzlibrary{ext.paths.ortho}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node (condition0) [decision] at (0,0) {foo};
  \node (condition1) [decision] at (3,0) {bar};
  \draw[arrow] (condition0.north) |-|[distance=0.5cm]  (condition1.north);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}



Simply change the first orthogonal connector (|-) to a straight connector (--):
\documentclass[letterpaper]{report}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows}

\begin{document}

\tikzset{decision/.style={
    diamond,
    draw,
    rounded corners,
    text centered,
    text width=0.4in
}}

\tikzset{arrow/.style={thin,->,>=stealth,rounded corners}}

\tikzset{x=1in,y=1in}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node (condition0) [decision] at (0,0) {foo};
  \node (condition1) [decision] at (3,0) {bar};
  \draw [arrow] (condition0) -- ++(0,0.5) -| (condition1);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}


When you use an orthogonal connector, TikZ adds another coordinate which will break the rounded corners mechanism.
